# What is the simpliest way to use fgets to get multiple inputs with strtok?

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

So I am trying to have my program read a line of user input separated by spaces and commas. The input is then going to be parsed to a struct. This is what i have written so far:

```
void playerFunction()
{
    Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
    Player player;
    Position position;
    Direction direction;
    char input[LINE + EXTRA_SPACES];
    char* tok;
    char* firstInput;
    char* secondInput;
    char* thirdInput;
    char* fourthInput;
    int secondInputInt;
    int thirdInputInt;
    char str[10];
    char str2[10];

    if (fgets(input, LINE + EXTRA_SPACES, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR! NO INPUT DATA!\n\n");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
        readRestOfLine();
    }

    if(input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')
    {
        printf("BUFFER OVERFLOW!\n\n");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
        readRestOfLine();
    }

    tok = strtok(input, " ");
    firstInput = strdup(tok);

    tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    secondInput = strdup(tok);

    tok = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    thirdInput = strdup(tok);

    tok = strtok(NULL, "");
    fourthInput = strdup(tok);

    strcpy(str, secondInput);
    secondInputInt = atoi(str);
    strcpy(str2, thirdInput);
    thirdInputInt = atoi(str2);

    printf("%s", firstInput);
    printf("%d", secondInputInt);
    printf("%d", thirdInputInt);
    printf("%s", fourthInput);

    if (strcmp(firstInput, "init") == 0)
    {
        if (secondInputInt >= 0 && secondInputInt <= 9)
        {
            if (thirdInputInt >= 0 && thirdInputInt <= 9)
            {
                if (strcmp(fourthInput, "north") == 0 || strcmp(fourthInput, "south") == 0 
                || strcmp(fourthInput, "west") == 0 || strcmp(fourthInput, "east") == 0 )
                {
                    if (board[secondInputInt][thirdInputInt] == EMPTY)
                    {
                        position.x = secondInputInt;
                        position.y = thirdInputInt;

                        if (strcmp(fourthInput, "north") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = NORTH;
                        }
                        if (strcmp(fourthInput, "south") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = SOUTH;
                        }
                        if (strcmp(fourthInput, "west") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = WEST;
                        }
                        if (strcmp(fourthInput, "east") == 0)
                        {
                            direction = EAST;
                        }
                        printf("success");
                    }

                    else if (board[secondInputInt][thirdInputInt] == BLOCKED)
                    {
                        printf("Board you are trying to initialise is blocked!\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else 
        {
            printf("error");
        }
    }


}
```

this is probably not the best way to do it but so far this is the only thing i have thought about. However, I realised the data from those 4 inputs aren't being sent into the struct. I have placed some prinf statements around the code to make sure user input is actually being read and it has. Does anybody know a simpler way to set this up? Also, i sometimes get segmentation error.

Comment: What is this line `EXIT_FAILURE;` supposed to do?

Comment: Sample input? Lots of debugging ouput, so what does it say with that input?

Comment: In most of the cases `strlen(input) - 1` leads into disaster sooner or later.

Comment: "*... to be parsed to a struct*" which struct?

Comment: The code is done with "*parse*"ing form the last call to `strdup(tok);` on. What is the rest of the code for? Is it part of you problem? Please be specific to receive specific answers.

Comment: an example would be "init 5,4,east"